# How can I set attribute which ends with dollar sign using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm trying to create a pre-processor that converts some custom markup in a file into attribute names which works with Polymer's data binding `$=` annotation, however I've come across a stumbling block.

I cannot set attributes using Javascript that contain a dollar sign.

I'm trying to convert

```
<p stuff="align bottom@md top@lg; offset 2gu@md; "></p>
```

to

```
<p align-bottom$="{{globals.abovemd}}" align-top$="{{globals.abovelg}}" offset-2gu$="{{globals.abovemd}}">
```

I have tried:

```
.setAttribute("align-bottom$", "{{globals.abovemd}}");
```

But it won't work because the attribute name cannot contain a dollar sign.

Can any one think of a way I can get around this?

Comment: Why do you think it can't contain a `$` sign?

Comment: why are you trying to add one?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer because it doesn't set the attribute if I use the dollar sign. I'm presuming `setAttribute` only accepts a-z, 0-9 and dashes, or something to that effect.

Comment: I'm trying to add the dollar sign because Polymer uses it to represent "show attribute if true"

Comment: `setAttribute` also accepts `()` or `[]` and probably some others. perhaps `.setAttribute("align-button\$"` is worth a try but `"{{globals.abovemd}}"` won't work anyway though.

Comment: thanks, `align-bottom\$` won't work either, but `"{{globals.abovemd}}` works fine. Sorry just noticed a typo in my example, should be bottom not button.

Comment: The docs I find for `setAttribute` don't specify a limit on the chars in the name, as long as the name is a valid HTML attribute name.  The HTML spec (as I read it) seems to allow `$` in an attribute name.  *That said*, I can confirm that Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) throws an exception if you try toput a `$` in an attribute name.  IE11, on the other hand, accepts it.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the DOM to manipulate the file using Gulp and Node. I suppose I could write to the file using Node but it's beyond my learning curve I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick(setting invalid attribute names), although obviously not valid in all cases:

```js
function setDollar(el,name,val){
  var attrs = [];
  var tagName = el.tagName;
  for (var i = 0; i < el.attributes.length; i++) {
      var attrib = el.attributes[i];
      if (attrib.specified) attrs.push(attrib.name+'="'+attrib.value+'"')
  }
  el.outerHTML = '<'+tagName+ ' '+name+'$="'+val+'"'+attrs.join(' ')+'>'+ el.innerHTML+'</'+el.tagName+'>';
  attrs.forEach((attr)=>el.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value))
}

setDollar(document.querySelector('#wow'),'foo','bar')
```

```html
<div id="wow"><p>something</p></div>
```

Still, needs checking for closing tag etc.

Comment: I like how you think, I should be able to work with this.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work because it wouldn't work with nested elements. I'm sure it would be possible to overcome this, but my knowledge is limited and I wasn't able to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the `$` anytime you are dealing with that property. The `$` is just reflecting the property to the attribute onto that DOM element.

```
.setAttribute("align-bottom", globals.abovemd);
```

Comment: But I need the `$` so that when the HTML is rendered it will dynamically show the attribute based on whether `{{globals.abovemd}}` is true or not

Comment: AST parsing is new to me, would have to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this gonna work

(you need put `align-bottom$=""` into your html first, this is just to update the value):

```
.attributes['align-bottom$'].value = "{{globals.abovemd}}";
```